# Why is the cout function outputting random numbers?

Tags: c++, xcode8

When entering a simple cout/cin function into Xcode ignorer to prompt a user to enter an account number. 
The result is this:
 " Enter account number :
 6.95322e-310"

What is this number that appears after every code function I enter?
I have tried to erase and recode and open a new project.

Thank you in advance for helping a nob.

[image]

Comment: You printed out the account number before reading it in. Also, why is your account number a floating-point value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please post text when possible instead of images.

Comment: It's always nice to help a nob :)

Comment: `std::cout` and `std::cin` are not functions. The stream inserters and extractors (`<<` and `>>`) are functions.

Comment: Thanks All!  Yes indeed I am as green as the grass so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, nob, when you go to a random neighborhood and you open one of their garbage cans guess what you'd see inside? I bet you 99.99% of the time you'd see trash (or gold if you're a hoarder).

Something similar is happening to your code. You're creating a new variable (`double accountNumber`) but you didn't explicitly set it to some value so its value will be whatever value that happens to be in the memory region that the variable using up, hence the random value.

Comment: I suspected that was what was happening.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `accountNumber` is uninitialized.

What you really want to do is something like:

```
std::cout << "Enter account number:" << std::endl;
double accountNumber;
std::cin >> accountNumber;
```

By the way, do you really want `accountNumber` to be a floating point number? You probably want it to be an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Thanks!  and I agree that account number probably shouldn't be a floating point number.  Indeed I am as green as the grass so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you output `accountNumber` before input it.

What you really want to do may be:

```
double accountNumber;

std::cout << "Enter account number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> accountNumber;

std::cout << "Your account number is: " << accountNumber << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! very helpful!